# How to get database name from postgres/mysql cursor object

Tags: python, mysql, postgresql

I have a several postgres and mysql cursor objects exposed to me, created in some universe. How to find the database name (and other info about that db) from these cursor objects?

`cursor.__dict__` gives nothing useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know about postgres but using MySQLdb you could always use the following:

```
cursor.execute("select database()")
db_name = cursor.fetchone()[0]
```

Maybe there's a cleaner way to do this...

**Edit:**

for other info it depends on what exactly you're looking for but for example to fetch table  names

```
cursor.execute("show tables")
for r in cursor.fetchall():
    print r[0]
```

There are many other functions available... Is there anything specific you're looking for?

Comment: Neither of those will work if the cursor is attached to PostgreSQL.

Comment: Yes I know... As I said I don't know much about PostgreSQL. Could always use some things like 'SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables' I guess. But I don't know any other way to get this kind of information directly from the cursor :(.

Comment: @t00ny thanks for answer dude! I figured out the one for postgres similarly `cursor_postgres.execute("select current_database()")`

Comment: @jerrymouse I'm glad it's suitable for your needs!

Answer (score 5):

If you also have the connection (call it conn):

```py
conn.info.dbname
```

Answer (score 2):

for postgresql:-

```
cursor.execute("select current_database()")
db_name = cursor.fetchone()[0]
```